# SQL to querying a table with a dollar sign

Tags: postgresql, escaping, looker

I'm using the Looker Dashboarding software (see: looker.com). It creates temporary tables in your database's `looker_scratch` schema with long names, each containing a dollar symbol.

These are straightforward to query using the "SQL Runner" in Looker itself, which somehow is able to escape the dollar symbol, but I can't query them using a 3rd-party SQL client.

I'm trying to query this table:

```
SELECT *
FROM looker_scratch.LR$5UA5D3XQDBPAYU0Q9FLFE_test
```

but get the error:

`the # of binded parameters < the # of parameter markers`

How can I query the table?

I've tried:

- `...FROM looker_scratch."LR$5UA5D3XQDBPAYU0Q9FLFE_test"` - says the relation does not exist
- `...FROM looker_scratch."LR\$5UA5D3XQDBPAYU0Q9FLFE_test"` - says the relation does not exist
- `...FROM looker_scratch.$LR\$5UA5D3XQDBPAYU0Q9FLFE_test$` - says syntax error
- `...FROM looker_scratch.$$LR\$5UA5D3XQDBPAYU0Q9FLFE_test$$` - says syntax error
- `...FROM looker_scratch.E'LR\$5UA5D3XQDBPAYU0Q9FLFE_test'` - says syntax error

Comment: Try `looker_scratch."lr$5ua5d3xqdbpayu0q9flfe_test"`

Comment: I would expect `select oid::regclass from pg_class where relname ilike '%5ua5d%';` to show you how exactly you should query the identifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try selecting exact identifier by pattern:

```
select oid::regclass from pg_class where relname ilike '%5ua5d%';
```

E.g:

```
so=# create table t."WeirdMix$" ();
CREATE TABLE
Time: 55.750 ms
so=# select oid::regclass from pg_class where relname ilike '%mix%';
      oid
---------------
 t."WeirdMix$"
(1 row)

Time: 90.814 ms
```

Comment: Fantastic! The issue in the end was really because Looker was telling me the table was in upper case whereas in information_schema.tables the tables are all lower case. Why didn't I think of that? *facepalm*. Thanks anyway :D